# Sending an email from a stand alone class (CAKEPHP)

Tags: class, email, cakephp-1.3

I have a class that is called jobs which is just a class I made which has a few add functions and read functions to and from a DB.

Now my question is since I don't extend appmodel or appcontroller, I cant use the email component can I?

What can I use to send an email inside this class. I tried the old fasion mail() with no luck..

Any help with be great.

Comment: Just to let you know this class is for adding a job to a database, its inside the webroot folder of my cakephp folder.

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing this class? Have you considered attempting to load it as a vendor or lib file? That way, you can still take advantage of the other methods that CakePHP has to offer.

Put the file in your /vendors folder and use App::import() to load it.

Answer (score 0):

You can, also (tho it's not the best idea) use a POST request and send the data to a cake action that will do the rest..